# Maven Managed Jars not downloaded

Tags: maven, jar, pom.xml

I am having an issue where the JAR files that I specify in my POM.xml file are not being downloaded / imported into my project.  I know that this is happening due to network restrictions that are implemented within my company.

Here are some examples of the JAR files that I currently require:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.enterprisedt</groupId>
  <artifactId>edtFTPj</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.3</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>xerces</groupId>
  <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I want to work with my network administrator to understand and the correct the restrictions that are in place that prevent the automatic Maven management of these (and other) Jar files (dependencies).

My question is... How do I specify to my admin where these dependencies are being downloaded from?  Is there a URL that gets built using my dependency descriptors that is attempted to be contacted to attempt to get the Jar files from?

Why am I able to download a Jar file using my browser where as the Maven Managed dependency downloads (via my IDE, SpringSource Tool Suite) seem to be blocked?

I don't understand enough about the Maven environment to help my network admin help me.

Thank you!

Edit 08/23/2016:

I am able to tell my IDE about our proxy server using the settings.xml file.  I am still not able to resolve my dependencies.  What I beileve is still missing from my equation is that I need to provide a 'Certificate' to my proxy server for it to 'open the doors' for me.  We have this capability installed on our network such that, every now and then, I need to 'sign in' to our network to allow the browser to work.  What I am doing, when I sign in, is getting a valid certificate.  I can see this certificate as being managed in my 'Keychain Access' when I look for it on my mac workstation.

So here's the question... is there a way to tell the IDE to where the Certificate is and how to use it?

I do appreciate the help!

Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're probably behind the proxy, and the browser probably is configured to work behind the proxy, whereas Maven doesn't.

In order to define proxy, you have to configure proxy in $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml:

Usually its something like this:

```
<proxies>
  <proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <username>mkyong</username>
  <password>password</password>
  <host>proxy.host.com</host>
  <port>1234</port>
  <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

Now regarding the repository. Maven by default uses remote repository called **repo1** but sometimes you'll want to define your own repositories (again, usually this is done in settings.xml file)

Usually organizations maintain proxy that has some UI and provides cache for third parties. There are projects like **Nexus** or **Artifactory** that provide a repository management like this. So usually you install one of those, and then configure the local Maven distribution to work against that manager.

Comment: Mark - Thanks for the input.  The settings.xml file.  This is for the Project I am trying to build or is that a settings file for my entire IDE?  Sorry, I am not sure where that is.  My workstation is an iMac.

Comment: Usually in organizations people prepare custom maven distribution (with proxy configuration) and spread among developers. You should download the maven zip, unzip it and define $M2_HOME environment variable. Then use $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml

Comment: Mark - After some further research, I understand what you're saying now.  Thank you.  Once I get my proxy settings in the settings.xml file I should be set.  I'll update my question with the results.